# Got text message with 'download' button, how would I look at the link source or gain further info to see if this is safe? 2.3.6metropcs

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, mms, malware, spam

In the 'messaging' app that comes standard with metropcs, I received a text message that had 'no subject' and was just a download button. I know the person, so there is no need to mention not to trust unknown downloads, but you never know when the forwarder is unwittingly passing on spam. I am mainly curious how you would safely inspect the link source or content. android 2.3.6 metropcs

Comment: You're right, it might have consequences to follow unknown links. However there haven't been browser exploits in the wild for Android that I know of. If you're concerned, use Opera Mini to access it via your phone, search Google for the main site or just ask your friend what he just sent you.

Comment: I wouldn't trust an unsolicited link even if it's coming from a trusted person. All too often, these messages comes from malware infected devices, it's not worth your time to investigate. To be sure, ask the sender what that link was about. Even if it's a valid link, if it's not worth their time to describe what it is that are sending, then it's not worth your time to investigate any further.